# Online tool to add amounts of memory from a table

Tags: web-apps, calculator

Is there an online tool that will tell me how much memory size that has mixed in MB and GB so I can get a better idea of how much is the total size used by all the files?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? What would you input, and what would get out?

Comment: So when I input these numbers along with the MB and Gb to calcuate how much it is total to give me the sum for how much the files are I have. Do I make myself clearly ?

Comment: You enter a list of sizes in MB/GB/etc and as an output you get the total. Correct?

Comment: Yes, I was able to do that in Excel but do not if this is correct. Maybe there might be one out there that are online that does for you.

Comment: You want to enter file sizes in MB or GB, and have it perform a sum regardless of the units used, correct?

Comment: @RockPaperLizard  Yes that is right.

Comment: I've updated your question to make it a bit more clear.  Feel free to make any corrections to my edits.

Answer (score 2):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/).  For example "[3721304KB + 700Mb + 20gb](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3721304KB%20%2B%20700Mb%20%2B%2020gb)", will output 23.81GB, or any unit needed, e.g. 2.381×10^10 bytes, 1.905×10^11 bits, etc.

The main defect of WA is that it's proprietary, and it's (deliberately) difficult to copy data from.